# How to get a list of skus in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, product

How to get a list of skus whiout using the looping in magento.
Example: I am using below code with my conditons.

```
$productsCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('sku');
```

Now I want to result as `array('A001','A002'....)` etc.
I don't want to iterate (loop) the product collection.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to retrieve the collection in that way, you will have to loop through the collection and retrieve the sku.

```
$skus = array();
foreach ($productsCollection as $product) {
    $skus[] = $product->getSku();
}
```

If you don't want that, you can just use a simple query because the SKU is kept in the `catalog_product_entity` table.

```
$conn = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$table = 'catalog_product_entity';
$q = "SELECT sku FROM {$table}";
$list = $conn->fetchOneFieldAll($q, 'sku');
```

Comment: if you have access to MySql `SELECT sku FROM catalog_product_entity /*where type_id = 'simple'`

Answer (score 1):

Retrieve the **read** connection you should use `->getConnection('core_read')` not `->getConnection('core_write')`. Whole codes is below which runs faster.

```
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$skus = $readConnection->fetchCol('SELECT sku FROM `catalog_product_entity`');
foreach ($skus as $sku) {
    echo $sku;
}
```